# Matching to a specific pattern

Tags: java

I am trying to preserve all the sentences between double quotes and put them in the array results[]

for example I can have the following code

```
public static void main (String[] args){

int i = 0 ;

System.out.println ( "words to be printed" );


}
```

In this example array results should have one string "words to be printed"

The technique I am using is splitting on the new line (\n) and checking if each String contains a double quotations and put it in results

I used `"your string here".split("\"")[1]` for extracting the text in between the quotations

The problem is that some Strings have quotations and some don't.

I tried: 
`if("your \"string\" here".split("\"")[1])` -> but this gives an exception if there is no quotation in the string
How can I check if the String has quotations or not?

Comment: Pattern, String, Matching - sounds like you want a regex.

Comment: I tried a few examples but they're not working

Comment: `str.indexOf("\"")` will be 0 or greater if there is a quote in the string.

Comment: Post what you tried, from there we can tell you how to fix those.

Comment: i can't see any double-quotes in the string in your example

Comment: Posting your input might help too, so we can see the different strings that you need to parse.

Comment: Do you need to differentiate if the quoted string is in a comment?  What about only one double quote in a comment?  What is your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can check to see if string has quotation

```
      if (yourText.contains("\"")){
    //do something
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an appropriate time to use regular expressions to match everything between the `"`. So a line like this

```
"myWord" and somewhere else "myOther words"
```

Should output

```
myWord
myOther words
```

Example code for paren matching:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");
for (String line: myLines){
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    while (matcher.find()){
        System.out.println("found match '"+matcher.group(1)+"'");
    }
}
```

If you only want to match a single line ignore the for loop, and just match against one input.

Comment: I figured you were iterating over some Strings.. if you aren't then ignore the for loop and just match a single input line.

Answer (score 1):

Use MyString.contains("\"") to check the presence of double quotes.
If exists you use split like you said.
If don't exists make yourString = "\""+youtString;  and use split after that

Answer (score 1):

If your string has two double quotes, then split("\"") will split in three pieces. So you can make a check like this (if expected not more then one double quote pair):

```
String[] s = input.split( "\"" );
if( s.length > 2 )
  System.out.println( s[ 1 ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting by `\n` use(If you are using java 1.7)

```
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

then use `"your string here".split(newLine)`. Hope this help.